# Pandas: drop rows after first occurrence of value in one column for each id

Tags: python, pandas

my Dataframe which I work with looks like this:

```
ID Alarm
1   1
1   2
1   3
2   3
2   1
2   2
2   4
3   4
3   2
```

I would like to remove all rows for each ID separately, after first occurrence of Alarm = 2. So the output should be:

```
ID Alarm
1   1
1   2
2   3
2   1
2   2
3   4
3   2
```

What is the simplest way to do it? Do maybe pandas methods for this case exist? I tried making something with `loc` : `df.loc[: df[(df['Alarm'] == 2)].index[0], :])` but it removes all rows after first Alarm = 2 occurrence, independently of ID.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `mask` created by [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with custom function.

For each group first compare [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html) values, because need include first `2`. Then compare by `2` by [`eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.eq.html). But also need match multiple values under `2` per group, so need [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) and compare with `0` - `False` rows are removed.

```
df = df[df.groupby('ID')['Alarm'].apply(lambda x: x.shift().eq(2).cumsum().eq(0))]
print (df)
   ID  Alarm
0   1      1
1   1      2
3   2      3
4   2      1
5   2      2
7   3      4
8   3      2
```

For better understanding with more data:

```
df['a'] = df.groupby('ID')['Alarm'].apply(lambda x: x.shift())
df['b'] = df.groupby('ID')['Alarm'].apply(lambda x: x.shift().eq(2))
df['c'] = df.groupby('ID')['Alarm'].apply(lambda x: x.shift().eq(2).cumsum())
df['d'] = df.groupby('ID')['Alarm'].apply(lambda x: x.shift().eq(2).cumsum().eq(0))
print (df)
    ID  Alarm    a      b  c      d
0    1      1  NaN  False  0   True
1    1      2  1.0  False  0   True
2    1      2  2.0   True  1  False
3    1      2  2.0   True  2  False
4    1      3  2.0   True  3  False
5    2      3  NaN  False  0   True
6    2      1  3.0  False  0   True
7    2      2  1.0  False  0   True
8    2      4  2.0   True  1  False
9    3      4  NaN  False  0   True
10   3      2  4.0  False  0   True
```

Comment: @jezrael-Can you please elaborate the above code in few lines.That would be great help.Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @jezrael. How would it be if I add one more column with datetime and now with my dataframe shaped with your advices, remove rows, which are for example 2 weeks older than the date from Alarm=2 still for each ID separately?

Comment: I think this is more complicated, can you create new question?

Comment: Ok, I'll do this

Comment: is the `eq(2)` checking if the `Alarm` column is equal to 2? If so, what is the syntax for greater than or equal to?

Comment: @thentangler - exactly, for greater than or equal is `ge(2)`